# Llenar Select dependiendo de un input con ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Necesito hacer un busqueda en base de datos con Ajax desde un input, y que se llene un select con los datos obtenidos

```
 <input class="input100" type="text" name="mov_int" id="movInt" placeholder="Ingrese N° Movil Interno" required>
<select name="nomCond" id="nomCond"></select>

$("#movInt").change(function(){
    var movInt = $('#movInt').val()
    $.ajax({
        url:'https://dubaidrive.co/fuec/php/operaciones/apiOperation/searchCond.php?movInt='+movInt,
        type:'get',
        dataType:'html',
        success:function(data){                   
            $("#nomCond").load('/fuec/php/operaciones/apiOperation/searchCond.php');
        }
    });
});
```

Este seria el controlador en PHP

```
$movInt = $_GET['movInt'];
```

$sql="SELECT * FROM conductores WHERE movInt='".$movInt."'";
$result=$mysqli->query($sql);

while ($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo ''.$row['nombre'].' '.$row['apellido'].'';
};

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que no hay ningún otro problema en tu código, desde PHP tienes que devolver los datos metidos dentro de etiquetas `option` válidas para que puedan mostrarse dentro del `select`. Con un simple `echo $row ...` no te va a funcionar.

El código PHP debe quedar así:

```
$movInt = $_GET['movInt'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM conductores WHERE movInt='$movInt'"; 
$result=$mysqli->query($sql);
$options="";
while ($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
    $options.="<option value=\"$row[nombre]\">$row[nombre] $row[apellido]</option>"; 
}
echo $options;
```

Aquí he usado la concatenación mediante la variable `$options`,  para dar un poco más de claridad al código. He metido todo dentro de una sola variable rodeada por comillas dobles, escapando las comillas dobles internas. Y no usando comillas de ningún tipo para referirme a las claves de `$row`, lo cual es perfectamente permitido en estos casos. Los `option` tendrán como `value` sólo el nombre, si quieres otro tipo de dato puedes cambiarlo.

> **Recomendación sobre la seguridad**
>
> Tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*.
>   Considera implementar consultas preparadas para prevenir ese riesgo.

En cuanto a la parte jQuery, no necesitas usar  `load` (versión abreviada) en una petición Ajax. Basta con recuperar `data` dentro del `success`. Aunque hay que refinar los parámetros en la petición haciendo lo siguiente:

- Evita pasar los valores en la URL, es mejor enviarlos como un objeto en el parámetro `data` de Ajax: `{movInt : movInt}`
- En el parámetro `url` ponemos la dirección sin más

Así el código queda más claro y puedes incorporar fácilmente un manejo de errores s fuera necesario.

El código quedaría así:

```
$("#movInt").change(function(){
    var movInt = $('#movInt').val()
    $.ajax({
        url:'https://dubaidrive.co/fuec/php/operaciones/apiOperation/searchCond.php',
        method:'get',
        data: {movInt : movInt},
        dataType:'html',
        success:function(data){                   
            $("#nomCond").append(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Listo, ya lo habia resuelto, estaba utilizando ajax, cuando con .load podia cargar lo obtenido con PHP, gracias de igual forma

Comment: @LuisMilano realmente `load` es por decirlo de algún modo, una versión simplificada de Ajax. Si haces algo así también debería funcionar: `success:function(data){                   
            $("#nomCond").append(data);
        }` El problema principal era que no estabas poniendo los datos dentro de las etiquetas `option` adecuadas por lo tanto nunca se iban a ver como opciones. Ahora edito la respuesta.